# Mass deployment on Raspberry Compute Module 3.0

Tags: image, compute-module-3

I am looking for the easiest method to backup/restore/mass deploy the raspberry compute module. (1000+ pcs)

I though about creating an image with raspbian and opencv but I still need to connect the module one by one. Do you have any idea ?

Best regards,
Antonin

Comment: Etcher supports writing to multiple targets
https://resin.io/blog/etcher-now-with-multi-write-and-compute-module-support/